# Sturm Seperation Theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

[image]

I understand the majority of this proof it's just these two assumptions. 
Firstly if $y_1'(a)\neq0 $ why does this mean $y_1\equiv0 $? could it not be a point of inflection ? And should $y_2'(b)$ be replaced by $y_1'(b)$?

Answer (score 0):

The key is here that $y_1$ is a solution of the 2nd order ODE $(py')' + ry = 0$, whose solution space is two-dimensional. So $y_1$ it uniquely determined by the values of $y_1(a)$ and $y_1'(a)$ - the trivial solution fulfills both being zero.

I'm inclined to think that it should indeed read $y_1(b)=0$ - otherwise the line with chosing the interval $(a,b)$ such that $y_1$ is positive in this would not make sense. Essentially, we are looking at two consecutive zeros of $y_1$.